# SQL - Generate Round robin number on insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, round-robin

I am deploying an existing bespoke windows service (C#) multiple instances that will reads from a single queue table.

The queue is based on the below simple SQL table.

```
Record-Id (int auto id)

Added-Date (Date)

Added-By (Text)

Data-To-be-Processed (Text)

**Pool-Number (int)**
```

How would I create a round robin sequence number for each insert given a max pool size? here I use a pool size of 3 (This can be hard coded).
e.g.

```
1 | 31/10/2014 | DATA | Pool 1

2 | 31/10/2014 | DATA | Pool 2

3 | 31/10/2014 | DATA | Pool 3

4 | 31/10/2014 | DATA | Pool 1

5 | 31/10/2014 | DATA | Pool 2

6 | 31/10/2014 | DATA | Pool 3

7 | 31/10/2014 | DATA | Pool 1
```

I have thought about using a Sequence table and increment it on each insert and reset it to 1 when it gets to the max pool size e.g.

```
TbSeq

  dbSeq (int) (Will contain 1-3 depending last insert)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `CREATE SEQUENCE`. There's a reason this was baked in the engine: implementing sequences yourself in a way that's safe under concurrency but doesn't collapse under load is not trivial. (The same applies to queue tables, incidentally, which is why Service Broker exists.)

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what I need. Jason

Answer (score 2):

If you can use the `RecordId` as an aid, then you could use [Modulo (**`%`**)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql)

```
select *, 1+((RecordId-1)%3) as Pool
from t
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/WNEIQM50851

returns:

```
+----------+------------+-------------------+------+
| RecordId | AddedDate  | DataToBeProcessed | Pool |
+----------+------------+-------------------+------+
|        1 | 2014-10-31 | DATA              |    1 |
|        2 | 2014-10-31 | DATA              |    2 |
|        3 | 2014-10-31 | DATA              |    3 |
|        4 | 2014-10-31 | DATA              |    1 |
|        5 | 2014-10-31 | DATA              |    2 |
|        6 | 2014-10-31 | DATA              |    3 |
|        7 | 2014-10-31 | DATA              |    1 |
+----------+------------+-------------------+------+
```

---

You could add this as a computed column (persisted optional, but recommended)

```
alter table t
  add Pool as (1+((RecordId-1)%3)) persisted;
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that `IDENTITY` doesn't guarantee a contiguous sequence (jumps occur on rollbacks or server restarts, for example). Depending on the application, this may or may not matter.

Comment: @JeroenMostert True, but a `sequence` doesn't either.

Comment: True, although a sequence with `NO CACHE` should leave gaps only on rollbacks or *abnormal* server restarts. An identity can jump even on a clean shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't depend on the `RecordId` *per se*.  It might have gaps.  The simplest way to do a real round-robin is to use `row_number()` and modulo arithmetic:

```
select 1 + (row_number() over (order by id) - 1) % 3 as poolnum
from t;
```

If you know that `RecordId` has no gaps, then you can use that instead.  Using `RecordId` is more efficient, because you can do the full calculation within one row, and even add a computed column:

```
alter table t add poolnum as (1 + (row_number() over (order by id) - 1) % 3)
```

Comment: You would need to add a custom function to use a window function in a computed column.

Comment: @Gordon : I think that second example is suffering a copy/paste? the text reads like recordID would be within it and you mean't the more basic recordID -1 % 3 version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SECQUENCE` as:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    Record_Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), Added_Date DATE,
    Added_By VARCHAR(50), Data_To_be_Processed VARCHAR(50), Pool_Number INT);
GO    
CREATE SEQUENCE Pool
AS INT
START WITH 1
MINVALUE 1
MAXVALUE 3
CYCLE
GO

INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES
('2014-10-31', 'DATA', 'Pool', NEXT VALUE FOR Pool),
('2014-10-31', 'DATA', 'Pool', NEXT VALUE FOR Pool),
('2014-10-31', 'DATA', 'Pool', NEXT VALUE FOR Pool),
('2014-10-31', 'DATA', 'Pool', NEXT VALUE FOR Pool),
('2014-10-31', 'DATA', 'Pool', NEXT VALUE FOR Pool),
('2014-10-31', 'DATA', 'Pool', NEXT VALUE FOR Pool),
('2014-10-31', 'DATA', 'Pool', NEXT VALUE FOR Pool),
('2014-10-31', 'DATA', 'Pool', NEXT VALUE FOR Pool),
('2014-10-31', 'DATA', 'Pool', NEXT VALUE FOR Pool);

SELECT *
FROM MyTable;
```

Result:

```
+-----------+---------------------+----------+----------------------+-------------+
| Record_Id |     Added_Date      | Added_By | Data_To_be_Processed | Pool_Number |
+-----------+---------------------+----------+----------------------+-------------+
|         1 | 31.10.2014 00:00:00 | DATA     | Pool                 |           1 |
|         2 | 31.10.2014 00:00:00 | DATA     | Pool                 |           2 |
|         3 | 31.10.2014 00:00:00 | DATA     | Pool                 |           3 |
|         4 | 31.10.2014 00:00:00 | DATA     | Pool                 |           1 |
|         5 | 31.10.2014 00:00:00 | DATA     | Pool                 |           2 |
|         6 | 31.10.2014 00:00:00 | DATA     | Pool                 |           3 |
|         7 | 31.10.2014 00:00:00 | DATA     | Pool                 |           1 |
|         8 | 31.10.2014 00:00:00 | DATA     | Pool                 |           2 |
|         9 | 31.10.2014 00:00:00 | DATA     | Pool                 |           3 |
+-----------+---------------------+----------+----------------------+-------------+
```